# Re-initializing string variables in Assembly

Tags: assembly

given the following program:

```
SECTION .data
x    dd 5
str  db "hello"

SECTION .text
  . 
  .
```

how can I change the value of the variables once inside the .text section

for example:  change x to 8, and change str to "bye"

I understand how to change the variable when its a number, like so:

```
mov [x], dword 8
```

but how do I change the string value? My first guess would be to:

```
mov [str], "bye"
```

clearly this can not be done. Would I need to change character by character?

Comment: Yes, char-by-char. You can also do 2, 4 or 8 characters together. You will need to use a byte, word, dword or qword register filled with the ascii codes as appropriate, taking endianness into consideration, and using whatever syntax your assembler supports.

Comment: @Jester would it be `mov [str], byte (ascii num here) `

Comment: In general you need to have a copy of the string you want to assign from, which means you will have two copies. The one that will modified presumably and the one your will copy from in order to restore it.

Comment: Yes, for example `mov [str], byte 65` would set the first letter to `A`. Your assembler may support that directly like `mov [str], byte 'A'` too.